# Prepared Statement when not knowing how many parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to convert a complex php file I made a year ago over to prepared statements. Parameters will be passed in like so:

```
file.php?name=John&age=20
```

However there could be many more parameters that are potentially used. job, address, phone number, etc etc. This is where I tend to get confused with prepared statements.

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT name, id, age, address, phone_number from person_db WHERE 1=1 ";

if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
   $query  .= " and name = ?";
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['age'])) {
   $query  .= " and age = ?";
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['address'])) {
   $query  .= " and address = ?";
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sis', $_REQUEST['name'], $_REQUEST['age'], $_REQUEST['address']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The issue here is `bind_param` because I don't know how many parameters could potentially be available.

How would I go about this in a logical manner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358874/dynamic-prepared-insert-statement/52244126 Might be of help

Comment: I'm not sure about `bind_param()` from the mysqli driver, but with PDO you can call `bindValue()` an arbitrary number of times, each with one value, so you can just put it in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very good question. And the solution is very simple.

What you need is called [argument unpacking operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-151). It will allow you to use an array of arbitrary length with `bind_param`. All you need is to collect accepted parameters into array, then create the types string dynamically and finally use the aforementioned operator:

```
$query = "SELECT name, id, age, address, phone_number from person_db WHERE 1=1 ";
$params = array();

if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
   $query  .= " and name = ?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST['name'];
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['age'])) {
   $query  .= " and age = ?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST['age'];
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['address'])) {
   $query  .= " and address = ?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST['address'];
}

if ($params)
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $types = str_repeat("s", count($params));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
} else {
    $result = $db->query($query);
}
```

Comment: Ok this makes some sense! How would the $types work if the data type was something other than a string? For example we could have an integer too?

Comment: Mysql would gladly accept an integer as a string. In the past we used to use `where id='1'` without a single problem so using "s" is just the same.

Comment: Just ran it on my test environment and it works! Funny that an integer is easily accepted as a string. Didn't expect that.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the process is going to be quite similar to how you build up your `$query` variable - i.e. you add to the parameters list one at a time.

Consider that `bind_param` requires two things:

First is a list of the data types as a simple string. So you can just have a string variable which you add to for each parameter, and then pass that to bind_param at the end.

Second is a list of parameters. This is trickier, because you can't just supply an array to bind_param. However, you can create an array of your own, and then use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to convert that to a flat list.

Here's one I wrote earlier (and works nicely). Note that it attempts to detect the parameter types and create a suitable string, but you could just build up a string manually in your `if` statements if you prefer:

```
$query = "SELECT name, id, age, address, phone_number from person_db WHERE 1=1 ";
$params = array();

if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
   $query  .= " and name = ?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST['name'];
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['age'])) {
   $query  .= " and age = ?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST['age'];
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['address'])) {
   $query  .= " and address = ?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST['address'];
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

if (!is_null($params))
{
  $paramTypes = "";

  foreach ($params as $param)
  {
    $paramTypes .= mysqliContentType($param);
  }

  $bindParamArgs = array_merge(array($paramTypes), $params);

  //call bind_param using an unpredictable number of parameters
  call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bind_param'), getRefValues($bindParamArgs));
}

$stmt->execute();

function mysqliContentType($value)
{
    if(is_string($value)) $type = 's';
    elseif(is_float($value)) $type = 'd';
    elseif(is_int($value)) $type = 'i';
    elseif($value == null) $type = 's'; //for nulls, just have to assume a string. hopefully this doesn't mess anything up.
    else throw new Exception("type of '".$value."' is not string, int or float");
    return $type;
}

function getRefValues($arr)
{
  $refs = array();

  foreach($arr as $key => $value)
  {
    $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
  }

  return $refs;
}
```

Comment: "because you can't just supply an array to bind_param". Yes, you can. Use argument unpacking.

Comment: I downvoted, because of `mysqliContentType`. The types should be dictated by the column data types not by the values. This adds unneeded complexity and could hurt the data in some cases.

Comment: @Dharman well it's up to the programmer (and good practice) to provide the correct type for the target field, don't you think? I wrote it to save myself extra coding by having to specify it every time I send parameters to the database. It's never caused a problem (even the null case) - but then again I wouldn't tell PHP to supply a parameter with a type which doesn't match (or isn't compatible with) the one in the target column (e.g wouldn't send a string to an integer field). As I say in the answer description, you can easily substitute that for hard-coded values if that's the preference.